# Adding dropdown list in html table in asp.net

Tags: c#, html-table

I'm populating ids and values from database and binding to dropdown list. and I want to add dropdown list to the html table generated in the code behind for each row of column 2. I'm giving different id for dropdown list but it doesn't appear to work and only the last row gets the dropdown list.

If I don't populate data and just use id attribute, the dropdown list appears in each row of the table. Similarly if I randomly add items to the dropdown list, again the things works. But it doesn't work with binding data.

Below is my code:

**.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                // Generate tabel for employer
                PopulateDropDown();
                Displaytable(numOfRows);


            }
        }

private DropDownList PopulateDropDown()
        {
            try
            {
                DC.dbConnection = Database.getInstance();
                DC.dbConnection.Open();

                DC.dbCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_Employee", DC.dbConnection);
                DC.dbCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                DC.dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SelectEmployeeList");


                lst.DataSource = DC.dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                lst.DataTextField = "Name";
                lst.DataValueField = "Id";

                lst.DataBind();

                DC.dbConnection.Close();

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return lst;
        }


 private void Displaytable(int rowsCount)
        {
            try
            {

                Table tbl = new Table();
                tbl.ID = "PendingTable";

                tbl.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                tbl.Rows.Add(new TableRow());

                tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Add(new TableHeaderCell());
                tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Count - 1].Text = "First Name";

                tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Add(new TableHeaderCell());
                tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Count - 1].Text = "Last Name";

                tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Add(new TableHeaderCell());
                tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Count - 1].Text = "Employer";

                tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Add(new TableHeaderCell());
                tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[tbl.Rows[tbl.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Count - 1].Text = "Email Address";


                const int colsCount = 4;

                for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
                {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow();

                    for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
                    {
                        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                        TextBox tb = new TextBox();

                        // Set a unique ID for each TextBox added
                        tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;

                        if (j == 2)
                        {
                            DropDownList newlst = new DropDownList();

                            newlst = PopulateDropDown();
                            newlst.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


                            cell.Controls.Add(newlst);
                            row.Cells.Add(cell);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            // Add the control to the TableCell
                            cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                            row.Cells.Add(cell);
                        }






                    }
                    tbl.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                Panel1.Controls.Add(tbl);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed somehow by just adding the items rather than adding the datatextfield and datavaluefield. So below is how i populated the dropdown items and displaying in each row.

```
private DropDownList PopulateDropDown()
        {
            DropDownList lst = new DropDownList();
            try
            {
                DC.dbConnection = Database.getInstance();
                DC.dbConnection.Open();

                DC.dbCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_Employee", DC.dbConnection);
                DC.dbCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                DC.dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SelectEmployeeList");

                DC.dbReader = DC.dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while(DC.dbReader.Read())
                {
                    lst.Items.Add(DC.dbReader["Name"].ToString());
                }

                DC.dbConnection.Close();

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return lst;
        }
```